# How to make flexbox items with custom widths jump to available space

Tags: css, multiple-columns, flexbox, masonry

I'm trying to achieve Pinterest-like layout, but with items of different percentage widths. Expected behaviour is pretty much like Javascript masonry plugin.

My flexbox code for some reason does not nake flexbox items jump side-by-side to another, event, when exact space is available.

**Illustration of what I'm trying to achieve**
[image: Illustration of what I'm trying to achieve]

**demo on jsfiddle**
[https://jsfiddle.net/31v7et9f/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/31v7et9f/)

html

```
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="item-1-4">item 25%</div>
    <div class="item-1-1">item 100%</div>
    <div class="item-3-4">item 75%</div>
    <div class="item-1-2">item 50%</div>
    <div class="item-1-2">item 50%</div>
    <div class="item-1-1">item 100%</div> 
</div>
```

css

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

/* parent */
.masonry {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

/* childs */
.masonry > div {
    background: gray;
    outline: solid 1px black;
    height: 100px;
}

/* child sizes */
.item-1-1 {width: 100%;}
.item-3-4 {width: 75%;}
.item-1-2 {width: 50%;}
.item-1-4 {width: 25%;}
```

Comment: You can have rows of flexible elements. When the row is full, the items will break to a new row or shrink. You can use columns, which will be vertically filled until the end of the flex-parent is reached. Basically like a row, just vertically. Here is your example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/d415y4qp/1/ seems flawed. One way to get close to Mansorny is to decide to let flexbox handle the size of the elements, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/d415y4qp/2/ but there is no perfect way. You may also investigate in CSS columns.

Comment: Thanks. It's an interesting solution, but it has one downside, the parent height must be predefined by user, so loses it's fluid heights. Nice approach anyway. CSS Columns are interesting too, but they dont allow such thing as: item width: 200% ;)

Comment: You are right, there is no nice way to solve this. I guess you were striving for something, that would try to fill up complete rows as good as possible. At least, you can provide a `height: 100vh` for a full-height solution that is somewhat responsive. You will have to decide what works better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox items are by default layed out in the order they appear in the html.  So, using your html and using `flex-flow: row wrap;` you'll get your 2 50%s side by side, but not your 75% and 25%.

```
/* parent */
 .masonry {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

You could rearrange your html (do some math in javascript to determine which order they should be in to tile).

```
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="item-1-1">item 100%</div>
    <div class="item-1-4">item 25%</div>
    <div class="item-3-4">item 75%</div>
    <div class="item-1-2">item 50%</div>
    <div class="item-1-2">item 50%</div>
    <div class="item-1-1">item 100%</div> 
</div>
```

You could also use order to group items that should be able to tile, though it's not perfect

```
/* child sizes */
 .item-1-1 {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}
.item-3-4 {
    width: 75%;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}
.item-1-2 {
    width: 50%;
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order:3;
}
.item-1-4 {
    width: 25%;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order:2;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/31v7et9f/2/

Answer (score 0):

We can use `flex-wrap: wrap; align-items: flex-stat;` in parent flex class and child we can use `flex: 1 auto;` so that it consider available space and align automatically.

```css
.fill-height-or-more {
 min-height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 align-items: flex-stat;
}
 .fill-height-or-more 
 div {
 flex: 1 auto;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
}
 .some-area 
 div {
 padding: 1rem;
}
 .some-area 
 div:nth-child(1) {
 background: rgba(136, 204, 102, 1);
}
 .some-area 
 div:nth-child(2) {
 background: rgba(121, 181, 210, 1);
}
 .some-area 
 div:nth-child(3) {
 background: rgba(140, 191, 217, 1);
}
 .some-area 
 div:nth-child(4) {
 background: rgba(159, 202, 223, 1);
}
 .some-area 
 div:nth-child(5) {
 background: rgba(179, 213, 230, 1);
}
 .some-area 
 div h1, .some-area 
 div h2 {
 margin: 0 0 0.2rem 0;
}
 .some-area 
 div p {
 margin: 0;
}
 html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="some-area fill-height-or-more">
  <div>
  <h1>Boxes That Fill Height (or more)</h1>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h2>Two</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error ut.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h2>Three</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error ut.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h2>Four</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error ut.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h2>Five</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error ut.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```